# How do I change the header in the template "Gossip Blogger Template"?

Tags: html, templates, blogs, blogger

I've started my new feminist blog. Sadly, the logo does not look good at all. I've tried to remove the shadow, but it doesn't helped at all. Here is how it looks like (up) and how I want it to look like (down):

[Both logos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la36G.png)

But I don't know how to do it. Here is the HTML code of my blog: view-source:https://glenn-gleich.blogspot.de/. This is what I have tried. I think I have to change following:

```
<!-- Begin header content -->
<div class='header-content'>
<!-- Begin Main Logo -->
<div class='main-logo'>
<div class='header section' id='header'><div class='widget Header' data-version='1' id='Header1'>
<div id='header-inner'>
<div class='titlewrapper'>
<h1 class='title'>
Glenn
</h1>
</div>
<div class='descriptionwrapper'>
<p class='description'><span>
</span></p>
</div>
</div>
</div></div>
</div><!-- /.main-logo -->
<!-- End Main Logo -->
```

I think it should be substituted with something like this:

```
<div class='item-thumbnail'>
<img alt='' border='0' height='72' src='https://3.bp.blogspot.com/address_to_image/name.jpg' width='72'/>
</a>
</div>
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you missing links at 'up' and 'down'? And could you please translate the sentence above the second code block?

Comment: @NathanvanBeelen uff, sorry. Thank you for your comment <3 ... I have added the image and translated the text now <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h1 class='title' style="color: #000">
    <span style="background: #000; color: #fff; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; margin-right: 2px;">G</span>lenn
</h1>
```

This would give the desired result, you can change it a little to your preferences.

Note: Do not use styles! I did it to make it easier to read, but you should put it in a .css file.

Comment: Thank you so much!